# In Windows firewall, what is the different between the two same default ICMP-ping rules?

Tags: windows, firewall, ping

In the Windows firewall, 2 default rules are identical:

- `File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In)` (technical name is `FPS-ICMP4-ERQ-In`)
- `Networking - Echo Request (ICMPv4-In)` (technical name is `CoreNet-Diag-ICMP4-EchoRequest-In`)

They only differ by their name (except if I overlooked something).
--> If I want to allow incoming pings, which one is the "official"?

note: the same rules exist for ICMPv6, for domain scope, and for outgoing pings (for a total of 8 rules)

EDIT: Thanks to the link given by Lex Li: the rules are identical, but disabling File and Printer Sharing through the GUI also disables the firewall rule of "File and Printer Sharing - ICMP Echo Request (ICMPv4-In)".

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1708119/allowing-icmp-ping-incoming-packets-in-windows-11-firewall